# Does Dreamweaver have dotted lines to show code indentation?

Tags: dreamweaver, code-editor

Does Dreamweaver dotted lines to show code indentation like in this image?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Dreamweaver does not display code indention marks like your screenshot does. About the closest you might get would be to turn on Hidden Characters (View -> Code View Options -> Hidden Characters). With that you'd be able to see the tab characters, but it would be nowhere near as good as what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are no dotted line tabs marks in Dreamweaver, but to make sure every opening brace has a corresponding closing brace in PHP, you can use the Balance Braces button on the left hand toolbar. It sort of looks like this: {|}

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

1. Go to View
2. Select Code View Options
3. Check the Hidden Characters option

Hope it Helps..